# String.Format() not invoking custom formatter

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have a custom formatter specified, basically like this:

```
public class NotationNumericFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType_)
    {
      return (formatType_ == typeof(ICustomFormatter) ? this : null;
    }

    public string Format(string format_, object arg_, IFormatProvider formatProvider_)
    {
       if (!Equals(formatProvider_) || arg_ == null)  // <-- I put a breakpoint here...
       {
         return;
       }

       // then a bunch of stuff happens here.
    }
}
```

What's stumping me at the moment is, the following code:

```
// _myFormatter is a NotationNumericFormatter which gets instanced 
// in the ctor of the class in question.
var result = string.Format(_myFormatter, (parameter_ ?? "").ToString(), value_);
```

Which is never, ever, hitting the first line in my formatter's `Format()` method. What am I missing here?  Is there some subtlety to `string.Format` that I'm missing?

Comment: What's the value of `parameter_` - do you end up with a format string that actually has any parameters (like `{0}`) in it? And is that meant to be `!Equals`, meaning an early exit if your formatter isn't handling the value?

Comment: sorry, was a typo. the issue is, that line with the `!Equals` is never breakpointed on. The `string.Format()` never invokes the formatter.

Comment: In your call to `string.Format`, what is the value of the second parameter (your format string)? If there are no formatting placeholders, I wouldn't expect the formatter to be called. That default value of an empty string doesn't look very promising.

Comment: @shambulator : I figured it out - thanks for pointing out the parameter_ for me. It turns out if it's null or empty, the formatter is never called. Guess I'll chalk this up to a case of the brain freeze...! Post your comments as an answer and I will upvote/mark your answer. cheers man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If parameter does not have {0}  then the formatter won't break point

this will breakpoint

```
var result = string.Format(_myFormatter, "{0}", value_);
```

this won't

```
var result = string.Format(_myFormatter, "", value_);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call String.Format(IFormatProvider provider , String format , params Object[] args ) the second parameter format hast to specified as a valid format string i.e. it cannot be empty.

Try to set parameter_ to something like "{0}" then it should work.